# How to inject into a java class that doesn't have any activity or fragment using dagger2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

```
Android Studio 2.2.2
```

I have a `NewsListModelImp` class which is the model in the MVP.

I want to inject my retrofit service into the model. However, as `NewsListModelImp` doesn't contain any reference to a context or activity I cannot call `getApplication()`. Which is what you would do if you were in a activity or fragment. I don't want to pass any context or activity in the constructor of `NewsListModeImp` as that would have to come from the presenter and I want to avoid any android stuff there.

```
public class NewsListModelImp implements NewsListModelContract {
    @Inject
    NYTimesSearchService mNYTimesSearchService;

    public NewsListModelImp() {
        ((NYTimesSearchApplication)getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

My Application class

```
public class NYTimesSearchApplication extends Application {
    private AppComponent mAppComponent;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        /* Setup dependency injection */
        createAppComponent();
    }

    private void createAppComponent() {
        mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .retrofitModule(new RetrofitModule())
                .build();
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
        return mAppComponent;
    }
}
```

My provides module

```
@Module
public class RetrofitModule {
    private Retrofit retrofit() {
        return new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public NYTimesSearchService providesNYTimesSearch() {
        return retrofit().create(NYTimesSearchService.class);
    }
}
```

My Appcomponent

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {RetrofitModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(NewsListModelImp target);
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Dagger-2`](https://google.github.io/dagger/) works reccurently. So if inside `Activity` (or `Fragment`) object is injected and it's constructor is properly annotated with `@Inject` annotation, the constructor's parameters will be injected too.

Suppose inside the application you would like to inject:

```
@Inject NyTimesPresenter presenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ((NYTimesSearchApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

The constructor of `NyTimesPresenter` must be annotated with `@Inject`:

```
public class NyTimesPresenter {

    NewsListModelImp newsListModel;

    @Inject
    public NyTimesPresenter(NewsListModelImp newsListModel) {
        this.newsListModel = newsListModel;
    }
}
```

`NewsListModelImp` constructor must also be annotated with `@Inject`:

```
public class NewsListModelImp implements NewsListModelContract {

    NYTimesSearchService mNYTimesSearchService;

    @Inject
    public NewsListModelImp(NYTimesSearchService nYTimesSearchService) {
        this.mNYTimesSearchService = nYTimesSearchService;
    }
}
```

Then everything will be injected properly.

Why the parameters should be passed to class as constructors' parameters? Such design pattern conforms [`SOLID principles`](http://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/5-class-design-principles-solid-in-java/). Object dependencies are injected into objects and not created inside it and such code is easily testable (in tests dependencies can be replaced ie. by `Mock`'s)

**EXTRA INFO:**

It is possible to inject objects implementing specific interfaces. Such technique is described [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/inject-interfaces-without-providing-in-dagger-2-618cce9b1e29). In your case `NyTimesPresenter` can have `NewsListModelContract` as it's dependency instead of `NewsListModelImp`. To do this add another module to your `AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = {
                RetrofitModule.class,
                AppModule.class
        })
public interface AppComponent {
```

`AppComponent` method to provide concrete class implementing interface should look like:

```
@Singleton
@Module
public abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    public abstract NewsListModelContract provideNewsListModelContract(NewsListModelImp newsListModelImp);
}
```

The implementation of `NyTimesPresenter` should change (just to replace concrete class with interface it implements):

```
public class NyTimesPresenter {

    NewsListModelContract newsListModel;

    @Inject
    public NyTimesPresenter(NewsListModelContract newsListModel) {
        this.newsListModel = newsListModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.. Thanks Zag