# Dagger - lateinit property presenter has not been initialized android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger

I am using `Kotlin` and java `together` in my project.

I created a `Bridge` class for use `kotlin` codes in java.

bellow is my `java class`:

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
    private Bridge bridge;
    private Boolean isAttached = false;
    private Boolean isVisible = false;
    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;


    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && isAttached) {
            isVisible = true;
            bridge = new Bridge();
            bridge.initialInjection(ChatFragment.this);
            bridge.loadCredentialsMethod(ChatFragment.this, appCompatActivity);
        }
    }

    public ChatFragment(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity) {
        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (isVisible) {
            bridge.stopMe();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (isVisible) {
            bridge.onActivityResultMe(requestCode, resultCode, data, ChatFragment.this);
        }
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        isAttached = true;
    }
}
```

And I created a `kotlin` class for use from `kotlin's` code like bellow:

```
class Bridge : HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    override fun supportFragmentInjector(): AndroidInjector<Fragment> {
        return fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector
    }
    @Inject
    lateinit var fragmentDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>
    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: AuthenticationPresenter
    val job = Job()

    fun initialInjection(fragment: Fragment) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(fragment.activity)
    }

    fun loadCredentialsMethod(context: Fragment, appCompat: AppCompatActivity) {
        val deepLinkInfo = context.activity!!.intent.getLoginDeepLinkInfo()
        launch(UI + job) {
            val newServer = context.activity!!.intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_ADD_NEW_SERVER, false)
            // if we got authenticateWithDeepLink information, pass true to newServer also
            presenter.loadCredentials(newServer || deepLinkInfo != null) { authenticated ->
                if (!authenticated) {
                    showServerInput(deepLinkInfo, appCompat)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun showServerInput(deepLinkInfo: LoginDeepLinkInfo?, appCompat: AppCompatActivity) {
        toServerFragment(deepLinkInfo, appCompat)
    }

    fun stopMe() {
        job.cancel()
    }

    fun onActivityResultMe(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?, context: Fragment) {
        val currentFragment = context.activity!!.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
        currentFragment?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}

const val INTENT_ADD_NEW_SERVER = "INTENT_ADD_NEW_SERVER"

fun Context.newServerIntent(): Intent {
    return Intent(this, ChatFragment::class.java).apply {
        putExtra(INTENT_ADD_NEW_SERVER, true)
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    }
}

fun toServerFragment(deepLinkInfo: LoginDeepLinkInfo?, appCompat: AppCompatActivity) {

    appCompat.addFragmentBackStack("ServerFragment", R.id.fragment_container_chat_mou) {
        ServerFragment.newInstance(deepLinkInfo)
    }
}
```

But when I run code get me bellow error:

```
lateinit property presenter has not been initialized
```

The error refer to this line:

```
@Inject
lateinit var presenter: AuthenticationPresenter
```

I used from this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166022/how-to-inject-into-a-java-class-that-doesnt-have-any-activity-or-fragment-using) but don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Bridge class is not injectable, you can add it to graph and make it injectable easily adding `@Inject` to its constructor

```
class Bridge @Inject constructor(): HasSupportFragmentInjector
```